# Are there any tools or NuGet packages available for C# (Windows Forms) that assist in visualizing Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: c#, grid, window, dijkstra, graph-visualization

I discovered an awesome Java project that visually demonstrates Dijkstra's Algorithm. Now, I'm curious if there are any tools in Windows Forms or NuGet packages that allow me to create a grid, similar to the image below. This grid would change the color of each pixel as the algorithm runs, providing a visual representation of its progress.

I'm looking for a solution to create a Windows Form with a grid layout similar to the photo. Alternatively, I'm interested in any NuGet packages that support creating Windows Forms with a grid layout like the one shown in the photo [Dijkstra visualization in Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipyrE.png).

Comment: "Find me a library that does.." is not on topic for SO, but java code is very similar to C# - have a go at porting the code over and ask us about specific problems when you get stuck